# Jagged Edges in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Anyone have any ideas as why my letters in Illustrator are suddenly jagged? I tried viewing in CPU and GPU mode but it still looks the same. I can't seem to figure out why this is happening?

[image]

Comment: Which typeface?

Comment: I can't see any "jagged" edges.  To me the curves just look a bit wonky. Is this a letter you drew, or is it text you converted to outlines, or a raster image you traced?

Comment: Hi Billy, Thanks for your reply! Yes, the curves are wonky. That's a better term to use. I did not draw this letter. The typeface is Adobe Caslon Pro. It looks like this before I create outlines and after I create outlines. All 100% vector and no raster images. Wasn't sure why this was happening? I'm wondering if this is just the typeface? Seems a bit odd. Thanks again.

Comment: @MLT Thanks for clarifying. I have now added an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I just tested the letter S in Caslon Pro against an S from another serif font called Cardo.

It would seem the S in Caslon Pro is indeed a bit wonky.  It's not Illustrator, nor your GPU, and it's not your eyes either!

[image]

Comment: I've never noticed that. Now I notice traces of "wonkiness" here and there in the font. It's probably intentionally made this way to give it a good shape at small sizes, but I would love to know the exact reasoning behind the shape. (btw, why is there a small notch in the Cardo S?)

Comment: @Wolff - you may be right that the curves are deliberately wonky for small size optimisation. That thought had also occurred to me. However this would make the font not so useful for large characters .  As for the notch in the Cardo S it looks like a rendering artefact in the screenshot I took.  It's not there when I zoom in further, or convert to outlines.

Comment: Maybe the idea is to use *Bold Display* or larger sizes.